# Why does Ajax request that has a URL with dot dot work?

Tags: jquery, yii2

## Where is the Documention for why URL with dot dot works

> I can't find where **dot dot** is supported in the jquery documentation:
>
> **Example:** `url: '../workflow/next-step'`

#### Working Code

The below code works, but I did't think dot dot was supported and I can't find documentation around dot dot. I want to be careful about using undocumented code features.

```
$.getJSON({ type: "POST", url: '../workflow/next-step',
    data: { 
        workflow: workflow, step: step, val: val 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('works'); 
    },
    error: function (exception) {
        alert('fails');         
    }
});
```

#### Backstory

Using Yii2, a MVC (Model-View-Controller framework), I built a Yii2-extension and wanted the site name to be flexible in the controller mapping so users could define their own site name.

**For example:**

Format is: `www.someapplication.com/site/controller/action`

I want to be able to configure a site for either route below without modifying the extension or hardcoding the site in the javascript or php code:

- `www.someapplication.com/maintenance/ticket/index`
- `www.someapplication.com/operations/ticket/index`

## Summary

If you know where the resolution for .. is documented please chime in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't find where dot dot is supported in the jquery documentation:

Because it has nothing to do with jQuery.  It's just a string sent to the server.

> Where is the Documention for why URL with dot dot works

In the case of describing a Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) you need to lookup the [RFC 3986 Spec - Section 3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3).  Excerpt:

> The path segments "." and "..", also known as dot-segments, are
> defined for relative reference within the path name hierarchy.  They
> are intended for use at the beginning of a relative-path reference
> (Section 4.2) to indicate relative position within the hierarchical
> tree of names.  This is similar to their role within some operating
> systems' file directory structures to indicate the current directory
> and parent directory, respectively.  However, unlike in a file
> system, these dot-segments are only interpreted within the URI path
> hierarchy and are removed as part of the resolution process (Section
> 5.2).